# sys.meta_path import hook doesn't call __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an import hook that's implemented using this [example](https://pymotw.com/2/sys/imports.html#meta-path)

I've modified it slightly so that the `find_module` is implemented like this:

```
def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
    name_parts = fullname.split('.')
    if name_parts and name_parts[0] == 'Hello' and 2 == len(name_parts):  # looking for the form "Hello.XXXX"
        return self
    else:
        return None
```

It works and I can call `import Hello.Something.SomePyFile` and use it. However, when I do `import Hello.Something`, the `Something` package's `__init__.py` isn't invoked.  Why not?

Comment: Now that you're returning `self`, is `self` actually a module loader?

Comment: @user2357112 correct, `self` implements `find_module` and `load_module`

Comment: Did you actually implement anything that would load `__init__.py`? The example doesn't do that.

Comment: @user2357112, no I didn't.  I wasn't sure if I was supposed to do that myself or not

Comment: @user2357112, and also I'm not %100 sure how I would do that.

Comment: The basics consist of finding `__init__.py` and `exec`ing the code inside in the context of the new module's `__dict__`. You may want to look at how the [built-in implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/importlib) does it.